# Remove left/right margin of a TiKZ Matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-matrix

Consider the MWE below. This produces a matrix with 2 overlapping rows (that is what I want), however, it is also creating extra whitespace on the left and right side (which I made red in the screenshot below).

**How do I remove this left/right 'red' whitespace with minimal changing the MWE? So how to get the same behaviour left/right as top/bottom?**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fbox{
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&,%
grayspacer/.style={%
  draw=none,%
  fill=gray,%
  inner sep=0pt,%
  },%
matstyle/.style={%
  matrix of nodes,%
  nodes={%
    draw=black,%
    rectangle%
    ,minimum size=0.5cm,%
    fill=black%
    },%
  nodes in empty cells,%
  column sep=0.55cm,%
  row sep=-5pt,
  inner sep=0pt%
  },%
>=latex%
]%
\matrix[matstyle] (mat)
{
  \& |[grayspacer]|   \& |[grayspacer]| \& \\
 |[grayspacer] | \& \& \& |[grayspacer]| \\
};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the tikz picture, which is Ok, but the `\fbox{}` which includes spaces around the tikz picture. See:

```
\fbox{
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}% Omitted
 % ... Omitted
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

The newline after `\fbox{` is translated to TeX into a space. The same happens with the newline after `\end{tikzpicture}`. To avoid that, you have to "comment out" those newlines, like that:

```
\fbox{%
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}% Omitted
 % ... Omitted
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Note that, inside the tikzpicture these kind of tricks are not neccessary, because tikz parser ignores all newlines, so most of the `%` you had at the end of several lines are not required.

I think you want `draw=none` instead of `draw=black` for the black squares, to avoid the misalignment with grey boxes which I think was unintentional). Also, since the fbox is tight, there is no reason for `\centering`. Final document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\fbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[ampersand replacement=\&, >=latex,
   grayspacer/.style={draw=none, fill=gray, inner sep=0pt,},
   matstyle/.style={ matrix of nodes,
     nodes={draw=none, rectangle, minimum size=0.5cm, fill=black},
     nodes in empty cells, column sep=0.55cm, row sep=-5pt,inner sep=0pt,
     },
   ]
  \matrix[matstyle, inner sep=0pt] (mat)
  {
     \& |[grayspacer]|   \& |[grayspacer]| \& \\
   |[grayspacer] | \& \& \& |[grayspacer]| \\
   };
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case a `\fbox` is surplus. The same border around `matrix` you can get with option `draw` in your `matstyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%ampersand replacement=\&, >=latex,
matstyle/.style = {matrix of nodes,draw,
                   nodes={draw=none, rectangle, minimum size=0.5cm, fill=black},
                   nodes in empty cells, 
                   column sep=0.5cm, row sep=0pt,
                   },
                        ]
\matrix[matstyle, inner sep=0pt] (mat)
{
            & |[gray]|  & |[gray]|  &          \\
|[gray]|    &           &           & |[gray]| \\
};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]